# (Unity2D) Time.deltaTime inconsistent with up to .02 seconds - Alternative?

Tags: c#

As I'm aware, Time.deltaTime is based on used devices' FPS. However, I still created following code, as it's the only way I figured out to create my game:

ObstacleMove.cs:

```
public class ObstacleMove : MonoBehaviour {

    public PlayerScript pScript;
    public ObstacleSpawn oScript;

    public float constantSpeed;
    public float destroyTime;

    private float selfDestroyTime;

    float seconds;

    void Awake () {
        selfDestroyTime = Time.time + destroyTime;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.position += Vector3.up * constantSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        if (Time.time > selfDestroyTime) {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
    }


}
```

ObstacleSpawn.cs:

```
public class ObstacleSpawn : MonoBehaviour {

    public PlayerScript pScript;

    float obstacleDimensionY;

    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject obstacle;

    public float randomSpawnMin;
    public float randomSpawnMax;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        InvokeRepeating ("Spawn", 2F, Random.Range (randomSpawnMin, randomSpawnMax));

        Vector2 sprite_size = obstacle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite.rect.size;
        Vector2 spriteScale = obstacle.transform.localScale;

        float sizeAndScaleY = sprite_size.y * spriteScale.y;

        float obstacle_local_sprite_sizeY = (sizeAndScaleY / obstacle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite.pixelsPerUnit) * 0.5F;

        obstacleDimensionY = obstacle_local_sprite_sizeY;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () { 
    }

    void Spawn() {
        if (pScript.isRight == true && pScript.inAir == false) {
            obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1, 1, 1);
            Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3(0.05F , (8F + obstacleDimensionY + pScript.playerDimensionY), 0), Quaternion.identity);
        } else if (pScript.isRight == false && pScript.inAir == false) {
            obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
            Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3(0.05F , (8F + obstacleDimensionY + pScript.playerDimensionY), 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

The code moves my obstacle object towards my player using the Y-axis. As you see in following line:

```
Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3(0.05F , (8F + obstacleDimensionY + pScript.playerDimensionY)
```

As my obstacle standard speed is -4(To make it go downwards), I countered this my inserting:

```
8F + obstacleDimensionY + pScript.playerDimensionY
```

To create a 2second gap before the two objects collide, where my player- and obstacleDimensions is the height of my objects in px/2.

At last, by using time stamps I can see my code is working. It shows a difference of 2-2.02 seconds before collision. Although this is rather precise, I need the difference to be a perfect 2 seconds.

I believe this can't be done with Time.deltaTime bcause of the FPS, so how can I rewrite this code without using it?

Comment: The most reliable/precise class for time in C# is the `Stopwatch` class. It basicly stores the number of ticks since 1970 and does a difference to give you the exact time span from start to probe